# How to connect Firebase with IntelliJ Community Edition (Kotlin Console Application)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, intellij-idea

I wanted to create a kotlin Console Application and use the Firebase as my Database to store some stuff, I was wondering how can I connect it with the IntelliJ Community Edition.

Comment: [Database view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html) available in Ultimate only. You can use [EAP version of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) for free  ~9 months in a year:

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov unless I'm missing something firebase is not a supported datasource, unless some magical firebase JDBC connector exists (but I wouldn't see how that's possible considering firebases data model)